# Get TableSchema from BigQuery result PCollection<TableRow>

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

When I run a query in BigQuery Web UI, the results are displayed in a table where both name and type of each field are known (even when a field is a result of COUNT(), AVG(), ... operation, type of field is known, of course). 
The results can be then directly exported as a table/json/csv.

My question is, when I retrieve query results in my java project, e.g. with a query:

```
String query =  "SELECT nationality, COUNT(DISTINCT personID) AS population 
                 FROM Dataset.Table 
                 GROUP BY nationality";

PCollection<TableRow> result = p.apply(BigQueryIO.Read.fromQuery(query));
```

... is it possible to obtain the schema of TableRow in `result` PCollection, without explicitly defining it? 
I think it must be possible, since it's possible with the same query when using BigQuery Web UI.
But I can't figure out how to do it ...

```
TableSchema schema =  // function of PCollection<TableRow> result ?

result.apply(BigQueryIO.Write
                .named("Write Results Table")
                .to(getTableReference(tableName))
                .withSchema(schema));
```

That way query results could be always automatically exported/saved into a new table (only the table name then needs to be explicitly provided).

Any ideas? Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Dataflow SDK doesn't expose a schema returned by BigQuery via Dataflow's `BigQueryIO` API. There's no "good" workaround within the Dataflow API alone.

Defining a schema manually is one workaround.

Alternatively, you could make a separate query to BigQuery directly via [`jobs: query`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query) at pipeline construction time, whose result can then be passed to `BigQueryIO.Write` transform. This may incur additional cost, but that can probably be mitigated by altering the query slightly to reduce the amount of data processed. Correctness of the output is not relevant, since you'd be storing the schema only.

Comment: That is true; using the jobs : query you mentioned does return a schema, but does not justify additional cost. The amount of data processed can be limited by incorporating 'LIMIT n' into the query, but only mitigates the cost when there are no aggregation functions used (such as COUNT(), AVG() etc.) - which is often the case, unfortunately.

There could be a bit clumsy workaround - copying only the first row of the original table into a new table (so that they have the same fields), then query the new table only to obtain the schema. ??

Comment: There should be little or no cost for the query to determine the schema. You simply need to set the [`dryRun`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query#dryRun) flag in your query and then there will be no bytes processed.

Comment: @DanHalperin 's answer should be marked as the correct!

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually - you should write the function which will iterate thru all cells of given TableRow and for each - get name and type and while iterating you will create respective TableSchema.
For simple schemas, I would expect, it should be relatively easy.
For schemas with records, repeated, etc. this could be more complex

Comment: TableRow is backed by JSON. JSON types are less expressive than BigQuery types. While it is possible to distinguish between a string and a number in JSON, it may not be possible to determine which numeric type (e.g., integer, long) it originated from in BigQuery. Also, if some values are `null`, you won't be able to say anything about its original type. Hence, the inferred BigQuery schema may not match the original one, even for simple schemas.

Comment: Thank you Davor, makes sense